# Barra de rolagem TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi-xe8

Como eu posso deixar a barra de rolagem no final do `TWebBrowser`??

Ou conhecem algum outro componente que interprete e exibe o html?

Ajudem por favor help!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode interagir com o Documento carregado no `TWebBrowser`da seguinte forma:

Crie 2 variáveis do tipo `Integer`, uma para controlar cada barra, vertical e horizontal!

```
var
  vVertical,
  vHorizontal : Integer;
begin
  vVertical   := 0;
  vHorizontal := 100;
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.ParentWindow.ScrollBy(vVertical, vHorizontal);
end;
```

Valores inteiros Positivos e Negativos podem ser usados para colocar a barra para cima ou para baixo, para esquerda ou para a direita!

Aguardo o Feedback!

Comment: Olá Júnior, Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer pela sua atenção e vontade de ajudar, Bom mas aí tem um probleminha porque estou utilizando o Delphi Xe8 Multi-Device, Então ele infelizmente não tem essa opção de WebBrowser1.OleObject ... , Você poderia me informar como fazer isso em Delphi xe8 Multi-Device?

Comment: Aqui estão todos os métodos e propriedades do WebBrwoser Delphi Xe8, > http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser_Methods   , http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser_Properties